# How I can work on sections of a json in python?

Tags: python, json

Hi I'm working with a json and now it occurred to me divide it by parts, ie the personal structure should be a section, another section or part address table. someone comes up and I can iterate? I tried the following but not working.

```
with open("prueba.json") as json_file:
  document = json.load(json_file)
  for item in document:
    print item['structure']["name"]
    if item['structure']["name"] == personales
        for data_item in item['data']:
             attributesName.append(data_item['name'])
             attributesValue.append(data_item['value'])
        tableH = (attributesName,attributesValue) 
        tableV=map(None,*tableH)
        doc.addTable(tableV,col_widths = [180,300],typeTable = PDF.HEADER,
        extra_style = [
            ('ALIGN',(0,0),(0,0),'LEFT'), 
            ('GRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 1, colors.gray),  
        ])
        attributesName,attributesValue = [],[]

  for item in document:
    print item['structure']["name"]
    if item['structure']["name"] == personales
        for data_item in item['data']:
             attributesAddress.append(data_item['name'])
             attributesValueAddress.append(data_item['value'])
        tableH2 = (attributesName,attributesValue) 
        tableV2=map(None,*tableH2)
        doc.addTable(tableV2,col_widths = [180,300],typeTable = PDF.HEADER,
        extra_style = [
            ('ALIGN',(0,0),(0,0),'LEFT'), 

            ('GRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 1, colors.gray),  
        ])
        attributesAddress,attributesValueAddress = [],[]
```

but print all the values in all tables.

This is the json document

```
[
 {
    "files": 0, 
    "data": [
        {"name": "RFC", "value": "XXXXXXX", "attId": 01}, 
        {"name": "NOMBRE", "value": "JOSE", "attId": 02}, 
        {"name": "APELLIDO PATERNO", "value": "MONTIEL", "attId": 03}, 
        {"name": "APELLIDO MATERNO", "value": "MENDOZA", "attId": 04}, 
        {"name": "FECHA NACIMIENTO", "value": "1989-02-04", "attId": 05}
    ], 
    "dirId": 1, 
    "docId": 4, 
    "structure": {
        "name": "personales", 
        "folioId": 22
    }
}, 
{
    "files": 0, 
    "data": [
        {"name": "CALLE", "value": "AMOR", "attId": 06}, 
        {"name": "No. EXTERIOR", "value": "4", "attId": 07}, 
        {"name": "No. INTERIOR", "value": "2", "attId": 08}, 
        {"name": "C.P.", "value": "55060", "attId": 09}, 
        {"name": "ENTIDAD", "value": "ESTADO DE MEXICO", "attId": 10}, 
        {"name": "MUNICIPIO", "value": "ECATEPEC", "attId": 11}, 
        {"name": "COLONIA", "value": "INDUSTRIAL", "attId": 12}
        ], 
    "dirId": 1, 
    "docId": 4, 
    "structure": {
        "name": "direccion", 
        "folioId": 22
    }
 }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    TABLE_WIDTH = 540
    json_data = []
    attributesValue = []
    attributesName = []
    tableH = []
    tableV = []
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(path, pagesize=letter)
    width, height = letter
    styleSheet = getSampleStyleSheet()
    doc = PDF()
    for item in documents:

        nameTemplate = item['structure']['name']
        nameTemplate = nameTemplate.upper()
        template=doc.Paragraph('''<para align=center fontName="Helvetica" fontsize=9>{0}</para>'''.format(nameTemplate));

        for data_item in item['data']:
            attributesName.append(data_item['name'])
            attributesValue.append(data_item['value'])
        tableH = (attributesName,attributesValue) 
        tableV=map(None,*tableH)

        tableNameTemplate = [[template]]

        doc.addTable(tableNameTemplate,col_widths = [480],typeTable = PDF.HEADER,
            extra_style = [
                ('GRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.5, colors.green),
                ('SPAN', (0,0), (-1,-1)),
                ('ALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1),'CENTER'),
                ('VALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'MIDDLE'),
                ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1,-1),colors.HexColor('#C59AF5'))
            ])
        doc.addTable(tableV,col_widths = [180,300],typeTable = PDF.HEADER,
            extra_style = [
                ('GRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.5, colors.green),
                ('ALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'LEFT')     
            ])
        doc.addSpacer(20)

        attributesName,attributesValue = [],[]
doc.save(path)
```